# LsaOpenPolicy is throwing exception in my code. Why?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I got the following code from a newsgroup posting. Strangely, it isn't working for me in Delphi 2010; An exception is being thrown at the LsaOpenPolicy function call:

```
function AddLogonAsAService(ID: pchar): boolean;
const
  Right: PChar = 'SeServiceLogonRight';
var
  FResult: NTSTATUS;
  //szSystemName: LPTSTR;
  FObjectAttributes: TLSAObjectAttributes;
  FPolicyHandle: LSA_HANDLE;
  Server, Privilege: TLSAUnicodeString;
  FSID: PSID;
  cbSid: DWORD;
  ReferencedDomain: LPTSTR;
  cchReferencedDomain: DWORD;
  peUse: SID_NAME_USE;
  PrivilegeString: String;
begin
  Result := false;

  try
    ZeroMemory(@FObjectAttributes, sizeof(FObjectAttributes));

    Server.Buffer := nil;
    Server.Length := 0;
    Server.MaximumLength := 256;

    PrivilegeString := Right; //or some other privilege

    Privilege.Buffer := PChar(PrivilegeString);
    Privilege.Length := 38;
    Privilege.MaximumLength := 256;

    FResult := LsaOpenPolicy(
      @Server, //this machine, because the Buffer is NIL
      @FObjectAttributes,
      POLICY_ALL_ACCESS,
      FPolicyHandle);

    if FResult = STATUS_SUCCESS then begin
      cbSid := 128;
      cchReferencedDomain := 16;
      GetMem(FSID, cbSid);
        //FSID:=PSID(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbSid));
      GetMem(ReferencedDomain, cchReferencedDomain);
        //ReferencedDomain := LPTSTR(HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cchReferencedDomain * sizeof(ReferencedDomain^)));

      if LookupAccountName(nil, ID, FSID, cbSid, ReferencedDomain,
        cchReferencedDomain, peUse) then begin
        FResult := LsaAddAccountRights(FPolicyHandle, FSID, @Privilege, 1);
        Result := FResult = STATUS_SUCCESS;
      end;

      FreeMem(FSID, cbSid);
      FreeMem(ReferencedDomain, cchReferencedDomain);
    end;
  except
    Result := false;
  end;

end;
```

Original posting may be found at Google Groups archive:

> From: "andrew"
>
> Newsgroups:
>   borland.public.delphi.winapi
>
> Subject: NetUserAdd and assigning user
>   rights
>
> Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2001 10:08:35 +1000

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: What is the Exception and what does GetLastError return?

Comment: The exception is: Access violation at address 77DE1E50 in module 'ADVAPI32.dll'. Write of address 0046165C

Comment: 1) Server initialization is wrong (as Remko said) - similar with Privilege, 2) GetMem(ReferencedDomain, cchReferencedDomain); <- allocated 16 BYTES, but under >=D2009 it must be cchReferencedDomain*SizeOf(Char) - in that case LookupAccountName could ovewrite your memory, 3) Handle from LsaOpenPolicy is leaked - missing LsaClose

Comment: I appreciate the corrections.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN docs you should not use an LSA_UNICODE_STRING with the Buffer set to nil but pass nil instead: LsaOpenPolicy(nil, ...

**/EDIT:**
The code below works fine for me using Jedi Apilib so I think something might be wrong with your definition (maybe calling convention?), so please add this to your code.
Also you are specifying maximum buffer size of 256 in the LSA_UNICODE_STRING's which is incorrect, in the first case the maximum buffer is 0.

```
uses
  JwaWinType, JwaNtSecApi;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ObjectAttribs: LSA_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES;
  PolicyHandle: LSA_HANDLE;
  nts: NTSTATUS;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@ObjectAttribs, SizeOf(ObjectAttribs));
  nts := LsaOpenPolicy(nil, ObjectAttribs, POLICY_ALL_ACCESS, PolicyHandle);
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('nts=%.8x', [nts]));
end;
```

Comment: Passing nil to the Server parameter of the LsaOpenPolicy function does not solve the problem.

Passing nil to both the Server and FObjectAttributes parameters of the LsaOpenPolicy function does not solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed/changed function, tested on Win7 under D2009 (but should work on older/newer too). Of course app. must be running with admin rights.

```
uses
  JwaWinNT, JwaWinType, JwaNtStatus, JwaNtSecApi, JwaLmCons;

function AddPrivilegeToAccount(AAccountName, APrivilege: String): DWORD;
var
  lStatus: TNTStatus;
  lObjectAttributes: TLsaObjectAttributes;
  lPolicyHandle: TLsaHandle;
  lPrivilege: TLsaUnicodeString;
  lSid: PSID;
  lSidLen: DWORD;
  lTmpDomain: String;
  lTmpDomainLen: DWORD;
  lTmpSidNameUse: TSidNameUse;
{$IFDEF UNICODE}
  lPrivilegeWStr: String;
{$ELSE}
  lPrivilegeWStr: WideString;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lObjectAttributes, SizeOf(lObjectAttributes));
  lStatus := LsaOpenPolicy(nil, lObjectAttributes, POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES, lPolicyHandle);

  if lStatus <> STATUS_SUCCESS then
  begin
    Result := LsaNtStatusToWinError(lStatus);
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    lTmpDomainLen := JwaLmCons.DNLEN; // In 'clear code' this should be get by LookupAccountName
    SetLength(lTmpDomain, lTmpDomainLen);

    lSidLen := SECURITY_MAX_SID_SIZE;
    GetMem(lSid, lSidLen);
    try
      if LookupAccountName(nil, PChar(AAccountName), lSid, lSidLen, PChar(lTmpDomain),
        lTmpDomainLen, lTmpSidNameUse) then
      begin
        lPrivilegeWStr := APrivilege;

        lPrivilege.Buffer := PWideChar(lPrivilegeWStr);
        lPrivilege.Length := Length(lPrivilegeWStr) * SizeOf(Char);
        lPrivilege.MaximumLength := lPrivilege.Length;

        lStatus := LsaAddAccountRights(lPolicyHandle, lSid, @lPrivilege, 1);
        Result := LsaNtStatusToWinError(lStatus);
      end else
        Result := GetLastError;
    finally
      FreeMem(lSid);
    end;
  finally
    LsaClose(lPolicyHandle);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lStatus: DWORD;
begin
  lStatus := AddPrivilegeToAccount('Administrators'{or any account/group name}, 'SeServiceLogonRight');
  if lStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS then
    Caption := 'OK'
  else
    Caption := SysErrorMessage(lStatus);
end;
```

Comment: Maximum Domain Length is DNLEN, defined in JwaLmCons which is 15.
But I think it's better to call LookupAccountName twice, once to get the required Length and once for the actual call.

Comment: For the record and other readers please state what the problem was (it looks like you are now using Jedi Apilib since you are no longer passing ObjectAttributes as pointer)

Comment: DNLEN addedd, thanks. Comments to some 'errors in code' I've added below question, but why LsaOpenPolicy raises exception I don't know, I would like also see definition of LsaOpenPolicy and TLSAObjectAttributes. It could be also something from other code (mem overwrite in other places - use FastMM+FullDebugMode), or even from other components (injected DLL's). @SteveL Try this also in new clean VCL project. For future, please use JediApiLib (Jwa*.pas) instead of other 'old' imports, and also for each WinApi function read documentation for them from MSDN :)

Comment: It isn't working after all these changes mentioned above. I will make my entire  project available as a download and then maybe someone can make corrections and post a patch back here. I have given up hope on it in the meantime, until someone can fix it. I have other urgent project to work on right now.

Comment: ^^: Here is the link to my D2010 project. If someone manage to fix it, please post the patch here. 

URL: http://www.ziddu.com/download/13052634/temp.rar.html

Thx!

Comment: FResult := LsaOpenPolicy(...
      ---> @FPolicyHandle);  because your LsaOpenPolicy definition is "PolicyHandle: PLSA_HANDLE", but not like in Jwa "var PolicyHandle: LSA_HANDLE", but again try to use Jwa instead of your/'others'(found on net) import definitions :)

Comment: I made the following changes: 

1. I removed LsaAPI from the program USES.

2. I checked that my TLsaHandle variable lPolicyHandle is indeed pointing to the Jwa specifically to line 1041 in JwaNTSecApi :

  LSA_HANDLE = PVOID;
  {$EXTERNALSYM LSA_HANDLE}
  PLSA_HANDLE = ^LSA_HANDLE;
  {$EXTERNALSYM PLSA_HANDLE}
  TLsaHandle = LSA_HANDLE;

.. It compiles now, but the function does not work ie The user is not granted the 'Log on as a service' right after the function call.

I tried passing the lPolicyHandle parameter both as 'lPolicyHandle' and as '@lPolicyHandle' to the function. Same thing..

Comment: Please see my updated project source code at:


URL: http://www.ziddu.com/download/13054008/temp.rar.html

Comment: What error code AddPrivilegeToAccount returns or message by SysErorrMessage(AddPrivilegeToAccount(...)). After you add this policy, you must close and open gpedit.msc, because it doesn't refresh immediately (at least in Win7). For test, you can make NEW clean VCL project with that code I've posted in answer, and in form caption you will see 'OK', or error message.

Comment: @SteveL: I suggest the same as kibab: make a clean demo project containing only the problematic code and share that here.

Comment: @SteveL: It seems you are copying parts of Jwa and use that in your own code. That is exactly our "nightmare" and we really cannot support that! PLEASE use Jwa units or don't use at all but don't copy parts...

Comment: Remko, I have copied and pasted code from many different authors usenet posts and that is why my project looks the way it does. My client is now reporting that 'Add to group' is not working for him (on a Swedish copy of Windows 7 32 bit and on Windows Server 2008) (whereas it works for me on an US-En copy). I will use Jwa. If I manage to get everything working, I will post my code back here. Thanks Kibab and Remko for their help. -Steve

# Compliments Of The Season 2010. #

Comment: I have a new issue. Please follow up to my new question at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504052/netusergetlocalgroups-how-to-call-it