# NetUserGetLocalGroups - how to call it?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I am using Delphi 2010, latest version (from repository) of JEDI WinAPI and Windows Security Code Library (WSCL).

I don't know how to call the NetUserSetGroups function. The way I am doing it, it is throwing an exception:

> Access violation at address 5B8760BE
>   in module 'netapi32.dll'. Write of
>   address 00000000.

Following is my code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, JwaWindows, JwsclSid;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NetApiStatus: NET_API_STATUS;
  dwEntriesRead, dwEntriesTotal: PDWORD;
  lgi01: LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  username: PChar;
begin
  username := 'Elise';

  NetApiStatus := NetUserGetLocalGroups(nil, PChar(username), 0, LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT, PByte(lgi01),
    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, dwEntriesRead, dwEntriesTotal);
  if NetApiStatus = NERR_SUCCESS then
    showmessage('Total groups user belongs to: ' + IntTostr(dwEntriesTotal^));

end;

end.
```

Would appreciate if someone could kindly show me how I can call this function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TL;DR, show us **relevant** piece of code, but fix `const PChar` first

Comment: Your pasted code does not call NetUserSetGroups.

Comment: I am calling the code from another unit, as such:

 AddUser(PChar('Linda'), PChar('asdf'), False);


The access violation happens when executing line: 
NetApiStatus := NetUserGetLocalGroups(nil, PChar(username), 0, LG_I ....

Comment: Like user205376 says and as requested in your other questions: please provide a clean project showing only the problematic code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483728/lsaopenpolicy-is-throwing-exception-in-my-code-why/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482296/translate-sid-to-name

Comment: Complete updated project code can be found here: http://www.ziddu.com/download/13082260/WindowsUsers.rar.html

Comment: @SteveL: that is again the full project and it does NOT contain a call to NetUserSetGroups. Please create a new empty vcl project and put in ONLY the call to NetUserSetGroups and describe which part doesn't work.

Comment: my dear Remko,

It is the NetUserGetLocalGroups call which is throwing an error. Do you still want me to make a project with code containing only that call?

Comment: @Remko: Please see the relevant code: http://www.ziddu.com/download/13082705/Unit1.rar.html

Comment: @SteveL: thanks for the clean code, perhaps you can replace the question text with it? If you I will comment what the error is and see my answer below for correct and tested code.

Comment: @SteveL: you are declaring a record (lgi01) and then cast this to a PByte. If you read MSDN docs it tells you that the function allocates the memory so you can just pass a pointer to (an array of) lgi records. Declare the dwEntriesRead and dwEntriesTotal as DWORD/Cardinal an pass @dwEntriesRead. When you are done free allocated memory with NetApiBufferFree. See my answer for complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```
type
  LocalGroupUsersInfo0Array = array[0..ANYSIZE_ARRAY-1] of LOCALGROUP_USERS_INFO_0;
  PLocalGroupUsersInfo0Array = ^LocalGroupUsersInfo0Array;

procedure TForm3.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  nas: NET_API_STATUS;
  PLGUIA: PLocalGroupUsersInfo0Array;
  Count: DWORD;
  Total: DWORD;
  i: Integer;
begin
  PLGUIA := nil;
  nas := NetUserGetLocalGroups(nil, PChar('rweijnen'), 0, LG_INCLUDE_INDIRECT,
    PByte(PLGUIA), MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, @Count, @Total);

  if (nas =  NERR_Success) or (nas = ERROR_MORE_DATA) then
  begin
    for i := 0 to Count - 1 do
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('name=%s', [PLGUIA^[i].lgrui0_name]));
    end;

    if Assigned(PLGUIA) then
      NetApiBufferFree(PLGUIA);
  end;
end;
```